# Cannot render child object in React JS table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render an object held in state. The contents of `this.state` is:

```
"statement": {
  "creator": "8ff243b2-f21e-43f3-9090-4aa679fbeb1a",
  "id": "bf4c965e-bd59-48c8-b31a-8f67529e5fde",
  "impactors": [
    "978388e8-2987-4c89-82b6-4da619d82935",
    "1d75e2a7-bf2a-4f55-ba68-373752b24f98"
  ],
  "score": {
    "impactors": 2,
    "net": 3,
    "percentage": 0.75,
    "total_votes": 4
  },
  "statement": "The Earth is round."
}
```

In my React JS app, I am able to render some of the child object (statement) but not all. Here is my code:

```
    renderStatement() {
        return  (

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Statement: </td>
                    <td>{this.state.statement.score}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        )
    }
```

As expected, the above code returns an error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {impactors, net, percentage, total_votes}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

What I actually want is `percentage`, which is a node underneath `score`. When I try to drill down and have it just render `percentage`, like this:

```
    renderStatement() {
        return  (

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Statement: </td>
                    <td>{this.state.statement.score.percentage}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        )
    }
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentage' of undefined.`
Any of the other objects (`'creator', 'id', 'impactors', 'statement'`) work just fine.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `console.log` right before the return to see what's actually in your state? `this.state.statement.score` probably doesn't exist when you try to render

Comment: How do you fill your state ? Provide more code please, it seems your state is empty when your component renders.

Comment: Can we see the full code?

Comment: But if the state were empty, why does it render ID, Statement, Impactors, or anything else except Score? If i made Score an array, it would also render.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGagnon - Yes, console.log(this.state) shows the whole document.

Comment: @Progger try to use `debugger;` instead and inspect your state. You have to be careful with the `console.log` because if your object gets mutated, the log will get updated as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:

```
    renderStatement() {
        const score = this.state.statement.score || {}
        return  (

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Statement: </td>
                    <td>{score.percentage}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do the following:

```js
renderStatement() {
    const text = (typeof this.state.statement.score !== "undifined") ? 
        this.state.statement.score.percentage : ''
    return  (
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Statement: </td>
                <td>{text}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    )
}
```

Comment: This generates the following error: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentage' of undefined```